# real time monitoring graph using google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I know that it is possible to create dashboards using data studio from various data sources. My question is whether is it possible to visualize a real time data graph using data studio, as in case of data coming from IoT devices?

**EDITED**

I am uploading a file from my local machine now. So I think now it's not possible to visualize the changes in the data studio if I change any data within my machine.
What I am asking is however is that, is it possible to visualize any changes occured in a google sheet in data studio in real time. Say that I changed or added some new data rows into my google sheet, is it possible in data studio to see those changes in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with implementing custom script for refreshing the reports.

Comment: Yes, but you can schedule your script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio currently does not support automatic real time updates / streaming data. After you open a dashboard, the only way to re-fetch the data is to use the dashboard's refresh feature.

If you require real time updates in your dashboard, please put in feature requests / vote for them [in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:321382).

Edit: There is a [third party Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-studio-auto-refresh/inkgahcdacjcejipadnndepfllmbgoag) that lets users auto refresh dashboards (does not work with Viewer credentials).

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeding in a sheet that is using data supplied by  the Google Sheets Google analytics plug-in, and that is definitely updating in Data Studio as the Google sheets report updates.

Comment: How are you updating the google sheets? Are you importing anything or you are updating it manually? I didn't used sheets so far so please help me out

Comment: I created a sample google sheet and using that data i created a data studio dashboard. But if i am adding any new data into the sheet, to visualize it i should refresh the data studio console.Is there any way now to automatically detect that change and shows in the data studio console?

Comment: How actually does this works? Can you please explain it?

Comment: The Data source is the sheet in Google sheets. Using the GA addon the data collected is automatically refreshed daily, There are 3 reports that are then imported into the sheet that feeds into Data Studio. I did it this way because there are 3 streams of data that I want to compare in a chart that Data Studio won't do.
I don't know what else to tell you. The end result in Data Studio is a time series line chart that updates daily.

Comment: I believe that what you are doing is refreshing the google sheets page. I want my google data studio dashboard to refresh automatically in such a way that i want the real time data monitoring

Comment: You can set the report I'm using to update hourly. That's as close to real-time as you'll get with that add-on. But you're confusing 2 issues. Data Studio isn't real-time, but will update from an external  source that's automatically updating.

Comment: google analytics plugin in google sheets right? and how can we update the data studio report to change hourly?